# How to use Greasemonkey to remove a href block

Tags: javascript, parsing, greasemonkey, html

I'm trying to remove the following line of code from http://trakt.tv/calendars/my/shows/ using Greasemonkey:

```
<a href="/vip">
    <div class="huckster-vip-square">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Support Trakt & become a VIP!</h1>
                <h2>Hide advertising, unlock extended features and help Trakt grow.</h2>
                <div class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See, also, ["How to use greasemonkey to selectively remove content from a website"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9169032/331508), and many others.

Answer (score 0):

You may try it with jQuery.
Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859024/how-can-i-use-jquery-in-greasemonkey) for using jQuery in Greasemonkey.

The JavaScript code would be like:

```
$("a[href='/vip']").remove();
```