# How to use Greasemonkey to selectively remove content from a website?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey-4

I have tried removing content (paid content) from [this website](http://www.monitor.hr/) with *uBlock origin*, *Greasemonkey* and Anti-Adblock Killer script.

I have tried running [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169032/how-to-use-greasemonkey-to-selectively-remove-content-from-a-website) but without success.
The ("paid") content I want to remove looks like this:

```
<div class="news" info="398825">
    <div class="normal" ...>
        <div class="supertitle">
            <a href="http://www.monitor.hr/marketing/sponzorirana.html" target="_blank">Sponzorirana vijest</a>
        </div>
        ...
```

I can differentiate "paid content" from rest of the content with this element:

```
<a href="http://www.monitor.hr/marketing/sponzorirana.html" target="_blank">Sponzorirana vijest</a>
```

I would like to remove every "paid content" ("Sponzorirana vijest") section from the linked website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That content appears to be **static**.  So just leverage the page's jQuery like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remove sponsored content
// @match    *://www.monitor.hr/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

$(".supertitle > a[href*='marketing/sponzorirana']").closest (".news").remove ();
```

If more of those blocks are **added dynamically**, use `waitForKeyElements()` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9169236/331508).  Something like this (untested in GM4):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remove sponsored content
// @match    *://www.monitor.hr/*
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
waitForKeyElements (".supertitle > a[href*='marketing/sponzorirana']", removeNewsNode);

function removeNewsNode (jNode) {
    jNode.closest (".news").remove ();
}
```

---

Finally, per Greasemonkey's own developers, switch to Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.  Greasemonkey 4+ has serious deficiencies.

Comment: It didn't work in Greasemonkey but it works in Tampermonkey.

Comment: Yeah, GM4 is like that. A lot. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the script that works, just paste it into tampermonkey or greasemonkey.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Disable for sponsored news
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://www.monitor.hr/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    $("a:contains('Sponzorirana vijest')").closest('.news').css('display', 'none');
})();
```

Script explained.
@match shows on which website to apply it.
Function parts is jquery that selects node of class *news* that is closest to the anchor tag that contains string *Sponzorirana vijest*, when selected *display: none* is applied.

Comment: Close, but the `@match` is off and `.hide()` is better than that `.css` call.

Comment: @Brock Adams, I agree that `.hide()` makes code shorter and therefore cleaner, but have in mind that it does the same thing like the css from the example.
And for `@match`, could you explain how it is off since the script works as it is.

Comment: Don't ask a new question in a comment edit.  We don't normally see those (comment alert only goes out once).  I called the match "off", both because it will break when the site goes to https, and also it **only works on the home page**.  Both are easy fixes. See the `@match` in my answer and note the asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this custom filter in uBlock and it works like a charm:

```
www.monitor.hr##.tag-sponzorirana-vijest.category-vijest
```